# How can we make sure LinkedIn Javascript login is secure?

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, authorization, linkedin-api

We've implemented the JavaScript login plugin for our site [using these instructions](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins#signin), but are now running into problems ensuring that the login is secure.

In particular, we want to check that the user ID and email address that the javascript sends back to the server are (a) really authorized and (b) accurate.  Otherwise, it seems like anyone who could get the application-unique user ID could easily impersonate someone else.  Worse, if we set up a way to merge accounts, they could just use the developer console to manipulate the JSON and send an existing email with their own user ID.

Is there an easy way to query LinkedIn on the server side to confirm authorization and details, or do we really have to go through the entire re-authentication on the server side [like this](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens)?

It seems like a huge duplication of effort, or without it, a big security flaw.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Seems there may not be a way to do that using the client API. Because API is intended to use as Linkedin authentication for linkedin backend, not for third party server use it as authentication. So unless there is a way to authenticate a token on the server side, there is no way to ensure the data is valid.